# What changes should I make in GAN architecture to make it work with my image dataset of shape (N, 256, 64, 1)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

My image dataset shape is (N, 256, 64 , 1) i.e. greyscale images.
Earlier I worked on image dataset with shape (N, 48, 48, 1) and used architecture of generator and discriminator as follow:

[image: Generator arch.]

[image: Discriminator arch.]

So what changes should I make to work with (N, 256, 64, 1)? I'm confused here because the height and width of images are not same.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Conv2D documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) in pytorch you can see that stride and kernel size don't need to be specified as a single value but can be a tuple(this can be leveraged to take a square input and have a non square output)

```
input = torch.zeros((1,256,64))
#input.shape is non square (256,64)
conv_layer = torch.nn.Conv2d(1,1,kernel_size = 1, stride=(4,1))
out = conv_layer(input)
#out.shape is square(64,64)
```

Another option is to use preprocessing to make your image 256,256 before running the network and post processing to make it 256,64 afrer running(eg. add grey padding for the inputs of the discriminator and remove the corresponding parts of the generated image from the generator)